# Fetching a single backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, fetch

I'm playing around with Rails application that uses Backbone to handle some data on a different pages, I have no problems with fetching Collections and creating new Models, but I can't fetch a single model from the server in order to perform, say, show or edit. I'm trying to declare `urlRoot` as per answers found in other similar questions here on SO:

```
class Entities.Product extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: -> 
    if @isNew
      '/products/'
    else
      '/products/' + @id
```

I'm using the following route to start the show:

```
class ProductsUnit.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
  appRoutes:
    "products/:id" : "showProduct"

API =
  showProduct: (id) ->
    ProductsUnit.Show.Object.showProduct()
```

Later in the code I request the single entity of the product:

```
Show.Object =
    showProduct: (id) ->
        product = App.request "product:entity"
```

Request then handled by the following handler:

```
App.reqres.setHandler "product:entity", ->
    API.getSingleProduct id
```

And it fires a fetch of a single product:

```
getSingleProduct: (id) ->
  product = new Entities.Product
    id: id
  product.fetch()
  product
```

As far as I understand I can pass an `id` from the route itself `"products/:id"` to the chain of functions that will eventually fetch the model and the `urlRoot` will be `/products/+ @id` where `this` will represent the id that was initially taken from the route. But it seems that it's not the case here, since on the success `isNew` returns as `true`, even though I'm trying to pass the id to make it `false`.

```
getSingleProduct: (id) ->
  product = new Entities.Product
    id: id
  product.fetch success: ->
    console.log product.isNew()
    return
  product
```

I'm fairly new both to the Backbone and Javascript, so maybe there's a critical flaw in how I see the logic. Any guidance will be much appreciated, I've been stuck with this quite simple issue for few days already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've swapped your urlRoot logic: when a model `isNew` it doesn't have an `id` yet.

So it should be:

```
  urlRoot: -> 
    if @isNew
      '/products/'
    else
      '/products/' + @id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! But otherwise Backbone assume that the for the model I'm trying to fetch `isNew` is true, even though I'm passing an id property -- `id: id`. Backbone debugger displays that there is a model with the URL of "/products/" and this model has entire stack of existing models in its Attributes. Are there any mistakes in the way I'm fetching the model?

Comment: I've updated the question per your observation, too.